# Laravel: Ajax call hangs server

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I have ajax call

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($('#realms').length > 0) {
      $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: location + 'ajax/status',
        success: function(msg) {
          $('#realms').append(msg);
        }
      });
    }
});
```

Which is handeled by function:

```
function ajax() 
{
  $realm = @fsockopen('somesite.com', 80, $errNum, $errMsg, 1);
  return view('ajax.servers', compact('realm'));
}
```

When i visit index page and after dom is loaded (when ajax call starting to execute) i try to visit another link  -  it just wait until ajax function executes (so, basically server is waiting for response of that function and i can't even visit another pages until it finished).

How i can deal with that? It is executing in 1 thread?

Comment: I don't get why you call `fsockopen` function inside an array? Shouldn't it be: `$realm = fsockopen('somesite.com', 80, $errNum, $errMsg, 1);`

Comment: @ArminSam ,  It is not important at the moment. I was inserting some more data, but i deleted it for minimizing function size. I'll remove array as well, if it is confusing.

Comment: Check your browser console. it's probably throwing an error.

Comment: @TheAlpha . It just can't. It is server-side function and also @ sybmol at the beginning of the function prevent from error output. It is made for the case when ip or port is not correct or enabled. But it is not important, please, see the topic name.
P.S: Browser console is clear.

Comment: Please check the console/network tab and make sure the url is right. Make sure your ajax call is reaching the right url, for testing, remove the `@` sign and btw, suppressing error is a bad idea.

Comment: @TheAlpha , Thank you for trying to help, but you don't understand. Function is working GREAT. So, it reaches destination, receives response and append that response Correctly, but it just block all incoming calls (like when i'm trying to request another page on my site) until that function is executing.

Comment: Oh! Sorry. But it's not sending sync request right? So it shouldn't block the browser.

Comment: @TheAlpha ,  yes,  it is sending standard async ajax request. It is not blocking browser, browser is working fine. Browser can't retrieve page because server is not responding while it executing function, which is launched by ajax request

Comment: Does it still hang if you remove `fsockopen`? Do you not need to call `fclose($realm)` to close the connection?